# How to consume WCF in Android Application with Channelfactory?

Tags: java, android, wcf, channelfactory

How to consume WCF in Android Application with Channelfactory or how to create a channel to my wcf service from my android application which is written in eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: WCF offers more than one protocol on different layers. Which one are you using? Probably you should provide the crucial parts of your WCF-service and also show what you have already tried.

Comment: `ChannelFactory` is .NET - you can't use it in Android.  You'll probably need to use something like KSOAP2 or some other library like that for Java/Android.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I did it with just creating WCF client in eclipse with downloading required packages. And used soap action in code.